# How to understand and fix the Segmentation fault in this code?

Tags: c++, vector, static, segmentation-fault

I'm a newbie doing an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th edition*, which goes :

> Exercise 6.33: Write a recursive function to print the contents of a vector.

My code, as shown below, was compiled without errors nor warnings. The function `vector_print()` printed the vector normally after the first item had been added into the vector. But after the second item had been added, the program was terminated by operating system.

I tried debugging. one Segmentation fault was generated when the statement `cout << *it <<" ";` being executed. it went like :

The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault

I did a little bit read about this fault, but still didn't get it. Can anyone tell me how to understand it and fix this problem?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void  vector_print(const vector<T> &_v);

int main()
{
    string s;
    vector<string> v;

    cout<<"Please Enter:\n";
    while(cin>>s)
    {
        v.push_back(s);
        cout <<"the vector is:  --";
        vector_print(v);
    }
}

template<class T>
void vector_print(const vector<T> &_v)
{
    static typename vector<T>::const_iterator it = _v.begin();
    cout << *it <<" ";

    ++it;
    if(it != _v.end())
    {
        vector_print(_v);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Misc Comment: Stop using underscores to start your variable names.
_v is a really bad name, just go with v.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett I just wanted to use  a _ to show it's an parameter rather than the variable defined within the function. But my experience on coding is quite limited.If it's really a bad habit, I would never do it again. Thx for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues, but the main issue is this line:

```
static typename vector<T>::const_iterator it = _v.begin();
^^^^^^
```

since `it` is *static* it will only be initialized once and all prior modification to `it` will be in effect on subsequent invocations `vector_print`.

If the *vector* is never modified `it` will already be at the *end* and therefore in subsequent calls to `vector_print` this line:

```
cout << *it <<" ";
```

will be dereferencing *end*. If you do modify your vector than it is possible that the call to [push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) will invalidate  `it`, the reference linked says:

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

You should not be incrementing the *iterator* without first checking if it is not *end*.

This is one simpler way to approach the problem:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void printVector( Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    if( first != last )
    {
        std::cout << *first << " " ;
        printVector( std::next( first ), last ) ;
    }
}
```

you would call the function from `main` like so:

```
printVector( v.begin(), v.end() ) ;
```

Comment: I think it's the new size() ruined it, cus function vector_print handled fixed size vector pretty good.Thx for your clear answer!Learned a lot.

Comment: @AlanWang updated my answer with a simpler approach.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour What's the"std::next"? My compiler complained that:error: 'next' is not a member of 'std'..

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It turns out std::next is a new feature of C++11. I changed the .pro file on my Qt creator. It supports C++11 now.And most important Your code works!! It's really neat..Thx a lot man!

Comment: @AlanWang happy it helped, just keep practicing and trying new things it will fall into place piece by piece.

Answer (score 1):

You increment the iterator without first checking if it equivalent to `_v.end`. It is illegal to increment an iterator that is equivalent to `end`. Also, `vector_print` loops endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

void print_vector(vector<int>::iterator i, vector<int>::iterator j)
{
  if (i != j)
  {
    cout << *i++ << " ";
    print_vector(i, j);
  }
  else
  {
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  print_vector(v.begin(), v.end());
  return 0;
}
```